# SVG with two shapes, two clickable links

Tags: svg

I've never worked with SVGs before, but have been able to create this shape that I need.  Two triangles, each with an image.:

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 6.7">
  <defs>
 <clipPath id="top">
  <polygon points="0 0, 9.9 0, 0 6.6" />
 </clipPath>
 <clipPath id="bottom">
   <polygon points="10 0.1, 10 6.7, 0.1 6.7" />
 </clipPath>
  </defs>
 <image xlink:href="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/30423_pets-products_january-site-flip_3-cathealth_short-tile_592x304._CB286975940_.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="6.7" width="10" clip-path="url(#top)" data-state='top'/>
 <image xlink:href="http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="6.7" width="10" clip-path="url(#bottom)" data-state='bottom'/>
</svg>
```

However, now I want to have each of these images link to something.  I tried adding a `<a xlink:href="url-to-go-to">` around the image and polygon tags, but that didn't work.

So, **how can I make two separate links (one for each polygon) within this SVG?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<a>` tags around the images work for me; perhaps you didn't close them properly?

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 6.7">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="top">
      <polygon points="0 0, 9.9 0, 0 6.6" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="bottom">
      <polygon points="10 0.1, 10 6.7, 0.1 6.7" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <a xlink:href="http://ebay.com">
    <image xlink:href="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/30423_pets-products_january-site-flip_3-cathealth_short-tile_592x304._CB286975940_.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="6.7" width="10" clip-path="url(#top)" data-state='top'/>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="http://amazon.com">
    <image xlink:href="http://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/04/01-cat-wants-to-tell-you-laptop.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="6.7" width="10" clip-path="url(#bottom)" data-state='bottom'/>
  </a>
</svg>
```